# dynamically add table row having buttons with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add button in table row with onclick fuction. for that i am using

```
        var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
        var edit = document.createElement("input");        // Create a <button> element
        edit.id = "edit"+saveCount;
         edit.type = "Button";
        edit.value = "Edit Employee";
        edit.name = "edit";// Create a text node
        edit.onclick = editrow(id);
        cell9.appendChild(edit);
```

in this code how to call function(with parameter as its id) on edit.onclick

Comment: `edit.onclick = function(){ editrow(id);}` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
edit.onclick
```

Wait for a function in order to execute it when the event occurs.

```
editrow(id);
```

Is not a function but the result of the function.

```
edit.onclick = function(){
    editrow(id);
};
```

Will works better!

Comment: yes it works!! thanks and some corrections are 1.parameter is passed when i used editrow(edit.id). 2. the function which i was using to add row(function addrow()) editrow() function should be present in that only.